# [iOS]How to customize SSL validation with NSURLConnection?

Tags: ios, ssl, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

For some reason I need to customize my iOS app's SSL validation so that, instead of trying to match the URL with CN field of the SSL certificate, it should check if the CN field contains something that I specified.

I am using the standard `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest]` right now, and there is no way for me to customize the SSL validation behavior using that.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is documented, complete with a code listing, in [Overriding TLS Chain Validation Correctly](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/OverridingSSLChainValidationCorrectly.html) on Apple's developer documentation site.  Basically, you create a new TLS policy object for the desired hostname, then create a new trust object with a set of certificates and that altered trust policy.

Just combine Listing 3 (Overriding the trust object used by an NSURLConnection object) with Listing 2 (Changing the remote hostname for a SecTrustRef object).